# The method ... is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java

I'm trying to complete this code where I need to calculate the density using the mass/volume the user inputs. I have to use two different methods, and call the second method, but when I try to it says, "The method calculateDensity(double[], double[]) in the type Density is not applicable for the arguments ()" W

What's causing the error? This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Density {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the mass and volume for your 3 compounds.");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            
            double[] volume= new double[3]; 
            volume [i]=s.nextDouble(); // registers user input for volume

        } //end for loop
        
        calculateDensity();
        
        

    } // end main
    
    public static void calculateDensity(double[] mass, double[] volume) {
//
        
        
    } // end calculate density 

} // end class
```

Comment: Looking at `calculateDensity`'s signature, it requires two arguments. You're calling it with 0 arguments, which is the cause for the error

Comment: You also have a bug:   `density[2] = mass[1]/volume[1];
        density[3] = mass[1]/volume[1];`  I think that should be 2 and 3 ;)

Comment: Another bug is that `mass` and `volume` shouldn't be declared inside the loop, but before it. Doing what your currently doing you're re-creating them at every iteration and losing their previous content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not calling the function with your variables. You need to write `calculateDensity(mass, volume);`. Otherwise, how would the computer know that you want to pass these two variables to the function? It doesn't work with the same names of the variables and the function arguments.

The variables `mass`and `volume` are not visible in the scope of the `calculateDensity()` function, because they are not defined globally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct arguments to the calculateDensity method:

```
calculateDensity(mass, volume);
```

calculateDensity is a separate method and it needs to receive the mass and volume in order to be able to calculate the density.

Answer (score 0):

you should call your method calculateDensity() whith the aruments as declared, mass and volume.

There are multiple other bugs in your code, this is really basic stuff so maybe figure some out yourself. Hope this doesn't sound too condescensing: we all have started out at one point and made all these mistakes, but getting someone on SO to solve all the problems for you is not the ultimate way to success.